# Mark coverage issue as resolved

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, sitemap

After submitting my sitemap.xml url to Search Console, I'm getting emails about a "coverage issue" and that `example.com/sitemap.html` has a meta no-follow on it.

I imagine the Wordpress plug-in I used has something that generates an `.html` sitemap as well as an `.xml`, which is fine, and it makes sense that that page would have a no-follow. But in Search Console, I don't see anyway to indicate that this page doesn't need to be indexed and that this is not an issue.

**How can I mark this issue as resolved?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks, like you submitted this `html`-sitemap to GSC as if it would be your main sitemap - if not main, then at least having equal importance as the `xml`-sitemap. Thats why GSC alerts you about noindexed url containing in the sitemap.

I would

1. inspect your sitemap setup: which sitemap(s) is/are submitted to GSC?
2. Then i would make sure, that the `xml`-sitemap is valid. It is valid **if it doesn't contain**:

   - non-200,
   - canonicalized,
   - noindex-ed or
   - closed with robots.txt URLs).
3. After it i would adjust the setup so, that GSC has only one single submitted sitemap - the `xml` one.

My thought: after in GSC appears single valid xml-sitemap,  the coverage issue disppears.